# 3d accelerometer data for classification

Tags: 3d, signals, accelerometer

I'm trying to train Wavelet neural network model for classification of 3d accelerometer data. I have signals along with x, y and z axis.
I want the model process the 3d signals as one input signal. Any Idea of how to combine the 3 signals into one signal?